# Wiremock not showing the failed stub difference in log when running Spring Boot Integration Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest-assured, wiremock

Wiremock not showing the difference of request which is stubbed when not matched. Throwing 404 error and in logs the following message is getting displayed.

```
                                           Request was not matched
                                           =======================
```

--------------------------------------------------------... (20142 bytes)]
Exception: [404 Not Found] during [PUT]

I tried to add verbose logging in two ways

1. add  in log4j2.xml
2. In application-test.properties tried with
   logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=DEBUG
3. Used RestAssuredMockMvc.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails(LogDetail.ALL); in @BeforeEach method.

Nothing worked. I expected to see the expected JSON along with actual JSON in log